# Rigid body fixed constraints looks like springs

Tags: physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I building simple car animation. I started with one axis with wheels. I have problem with fixed constraint, it behave like some spring, i connect cylinders and cube like on picture. I attached also video what happens :-/ Do you know why something like this occur ?

Picture:
[image]

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTU5fxMvxbk

Comment: Try increasing the number of *constraint iterations* in *Properties > Scene > Rigid body world*

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the number of constraint iterations and simulation steps in *Properties > Scene > Rigid body world*:

[image]

10 iterations and 60 steps:

[image]

100 iterations and 120 steps:

[image]